# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) issue in Nodejs app

Tags: html, node.js

I need help. I looked up the solutions here but still couldn't find it. So I'm practicing something in Goorm ide and I have come to a dead-end.  I am trying to link main.js(which is in js folder) file by putting the script in the footer.  But I'm getting an error which says

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`
I also uploaded some png files in lib folder and I'm getting the same error after trying to access those in an ejs template.

Root folder consists of js,  lib and views folder and some others which are not relevant.

To link the main.js in footer.ejs(which is in partials folder inside views), I used 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/main.js"></script>`.
The png images which are uploaded in lib/images folder, I tried to access those from an ejs template in views so I used 
`<img src="../lib/images/image1.png">`.
I am getting that error in both the cases. It would be highly appreciated if someone could help. This is how my root folder looks like - 
[image]

**EDITED:**
This is the app.js code:

```
require('dotenv').config();
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var indexRoute = require("./routes/index");
var flash = require("connect-flash-plus");
var session = require('express-session');

// APP CONFIG
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.set('json spaces', 2);
app.use(session({
    secret: 'boom',
    cookie: { maxAge: 60000 },
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));

app.use(flash());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.error = req.flash("error");
    next();
});


// routes

app.use(indexRoute);

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server has started");
})
```

Comment: Please post the code in your main Node.js file.

Comment: Hi. I've edited the OP. Please check. The photo I've given, it is a mockup I've created to explain my issue. I thought there might be a problem in the way I have pointed to the folders.

Comment: Okay, according to your express configuration, your web browser will only be able to access files within the `public` folder.

Comment: So I should put main.js file and all the png files in public folder?

Comment: Yes. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Express configuration specifies that all of your static files will be accessed from the `public` directory:

```js
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

This means that any files you want to access in your web browser must be within this directory (or a subdirectory of it).

For instance, if you want to access `main.js`, and it's location in `public/main.js`, you would access it on the frontend like this:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="/main.js"></script>
```

Note that on the frontend, you must not include the `public/` prefix.

Comment: Hey, what you said worked. I moved the main.js file in the public/js directory. And used ```<script type="text/javascript" src="../public/js/main.js"></script>``` in my ejs template. But what you said not to use public. Is that bad practice to use public in the script tags? Another question I have is, should I put the png files in the public folder as well?

Comment: I would say it's probably bad practice, only because the [Express documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) demonstrates that it isn't used. But it probably won't hurt. Regarding images, yes, all files you want to access on the frontend should be in the `public` folder. You can add a `public/images` directory if you want, to keep things tidy.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please don't forget to give it an upvote and mark it as the accepted answer. I would greatly appreciate it. (Otherwise I won't get any rep for my time.) Thanks!

Comment: Hey, it was helpful. Thanks a lot, man. Learnt a new thing from your answer about the public directory. Thanks again.

Comment: @Zak Glad I could help!